# Laravel routes have folder name in it

Tags: php, url, laravel-5, routes

When i hit url the route needs to be configured with a prefix folder name i.e "laravel/"
for example 
For Url:
http://localhost/laravel/someurl

```
Route::get('laravel/someurl', function () {
return "asdasd";
});
```

How to remove the folder name for appearing in routes

Comment: Remove `laravel/` from first argument is didn't work, right?

Comment: Yes i already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

if you just want add some prefix you can use below code for group of code

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'app'], function () { 
  Route::get('package_type',['as'=>'package_type','uses'=>'UserController@package_type']);
});
```

for getting this root you need to hit

```
your_url.com/app/package_type
```

hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove folder prefix, you should set web server document root to `public` folder. For example, if use `php-cli` to run PHP simple server, use option `-t` to change document root:

```
php -S localhost:80 -t /path/to/laravel-project/public
```

Now, you can see that prefix is gone.

Similarly, if you use other servers such as [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#conf_structure), you only need to modify the settings.